# citation style for polish

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

I have a rather unusual problem, because I am writing my master's thesis and I am obliged to quote in a specific way (in the text), which latex does not offer, and I cannot change it myself.

for example:
I have to provide [author's name, year, pages] exactly this way, without "and" or "&". If there are **two** or **three authors**, then [surname 1, surname 2, surname 3, year, pages], while if there are **more than three**, I only have to pay the surname of the first of them, ie [author 1, year, pages]

I use https://www.overleaf.com/

Would anyone be able to help with this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify what you mean by "quote". Specifically, are you referring to the way the in-text citation call-outs should be formatted, how the bibliographic entries should be formatted, or maybe both?

Comment: by quote I mean - style of citation in the text for example: 
...no purse as fully me or point. Covered ten nor comfort offices carried **[Cooper, 2002, str. 43-45]***.